# Enter click on jqgrid save button is not working but mouse click is working fine

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have changed the span tag of save button to anchor tag to let the user to access the element using the keyboard. Now when I click enter button its just setting edit changing to edit button, but when I click on the save button using mouse its onclick event is triggering fine.

Comment: To help your users as much as possible you should use tags for the things you want to accomplish. For instance a button should be a <button> tag to get all the affordances needed for screen-readers and keyboard users.

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!